# What is PyMOLs search path for scripts?

Tags: pymol

I know I can run my PyMOL scripts if I specify a valid path from the current working directory and also using absolute paths, but can I have a central script repository, so I don't always need to specify the full path or copy my scripts around from project to project?

Environment info:

```
Kernel: Linux 5.6.8-1-MANJARO x86_64
Python: 3.8.2
Python2: 2.7.18
PyMOL: 2.3.0 Open-Source
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pymolrc](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Pymolrc) and create aliases to your scripts.

If your script is located e.g. in

```
/Users/tillyboy/pymolscripts/myscript1.pml
```

Just enter this line to your pymolrc:

```
alias myscript1, run /Users/tillyboy/pymolscripts/script1.pml
```

Now myscript1 is available for all your Pymol sessions independent of your current working directory.